# Why is the first date not being added to an array

Tags: javascript

Why is the first date not being added to this array?

```
function createArrayOfDates(start, end) {
    var dateArray = [];

    while(start < end) {
      dateArray.push(start);
      start = new Date(start.setDate( start.getDate() + 1 ));
    }

    return dateArray;
}

start = new Date(2015, 01, 01);
end = new Date(2015, 01, 05);
console.log(createArrayOfDates(start, end));
```

The Output I expect should include the first date (2015/01/01) but the array starts at the second.

Any ideas?

Comment: By the way: don't start integers with a zero. `01` is *octal*, in otherwords: `010 === 8`. Also, the month argument to `Date` is 0-indexed. In other words, `Date(2015, 1, 1)` is the 1st of *feb* (maybe you know this, but it's implied in your question that you expected *jan*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Date` is not a primitive-type, it is passed by reference. That means you need to *clone* the value of `start` before pushing it into the results array:

```
dateArray.push(new Date(start));
```

Otherwise, the `start` variable and the newly-pushed-element in the array would still be referencing the same value.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
<script>
function createArrayOfDates(start, end) {
    var dateArray = [];

    while(start < end) {
      dateArray.push(start);
      start = new Date(start);
    }

    return dateArray;
}
function getMyDateFormat(date) {
    var d = date ? new Date(date) : new Date;
    var dt = [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay()+1].join("/");
    return dt;
}
start = getMyDateFormat(new Date(2015, 01, 01));
end = getMyDateFormat(new Date(2015, 01, 05));

console.log(createArrayOfDates(start, end));

</script>
```

**Result:**

```
["2015/1/1"]
```